# objdump from inside emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, objdump

Assuming I have my working folder as `~/X/` and the binaries after compiling are in `~/X/bin/`
I usually first get the objdump like so:

```
objdump -D ~/X/bin/bin1 > bin1.list
```

then `emacs bin1.list&`

How is it possible to assign a function in `.emacs` to open a temporary buffer in Emacs and execute `objdump -D` in on the binary in it directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, by default the command <kbd>M-!</kbd> (`shell-command`) outputs shell output to a default output buffer.

<kbd>M-!</kbd> `objdump -D /bin/ls`

If you want to change the name of the output buffer, you can invoke `shell-command` through some elisp:

`(shell-command "objdump -D /bin/ls" "ls.dump")`

or

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-w</kbd> (`write-file`) - to write the shell output buffer to a file

**Edit:**

Example which grabs file at point if available, or prompts the user

```
(defun my-objdump-file (&optional file)
  (interactive)
  (unless file 
    (setq file (expand-file-name (or (thing-at-point 'filename)
                     (read-file-name "File: ")))))
  (when file
    (shell-command (concat "objdump -D "
               file)
           "*Objdump Output*")))
```

Comment: Thanks Assem. You are very close to what I am looking for. See, I don't want to keep any file saved on disk "unless I choose to". I want to be in emacs, and execute a command that knows the path of where the binary is and view the results in a "temp buffer" just like the *scratch* buffer in emacs. I don't want it to save the output to any file on disk unless I choose to do a "save as".
It will also be nice if this temp buffer can be names something like *Objdump*.
Could you modify your function to do that?
Much appreciated.

Comment: @Ammari: The `my-objdump-file` function only creates a *buffer* called "*Objdump Output*" with the results of `objdump -D file`.  No files are created :)  But, if you ever need a file saved, you can use `C-x C-w` inside the objdump output buffer to choose a new filename to save the output to.